# BSD Packet Interception (Not Copying)

Tags: c, freebsd, packet, intercept

I want to get in the middle of packet forwarding (Not routing). For example, the system is a layer 2 bridge between hosts and their gateway. I want to check the layer 7 for string or whatever "foo" and forward/drop/delay the packet based on the result. What I am having trouble with is intercepting the packet.

What I have read so far:

I know I can get the copy of packet from BPF device (Usenix paper by Steven McCanne and Van Jacobson http://www.tcpdump.org/papers/bpf-usenix93.pdf ). that's good for sniffing but not for me.

I can access the PF device and set the filtering rules which is good for forwarding or dropping decisions, but not for inspection. man pf (4)

I can get packets into the ALTQ queues, BUT I do not know how to access the individual packets located in the queue. man altq(9)

I have also looking into the source code for PF(/usr/src/sys/contrib/pf/net ), PFCTL (/usr/src/contrib/pf/pfctl) and ALTQ(/usr/src/sys/contrib/altq/altq).
On FreeBSD 9.1 machine

I am not C expert, but I am good with it.

Maybe I am getting tired today with all the reading and missed something trivial. Please forgive me if so. Plus, this will be a very good find fro those looking into the subject.

P.S. There is a way of controlling the flow of "foo", by detecting "foo" in packet and denying the answer to that from coming back by setting up the filter for answer to that request. This is NOT what I am trying to achieve. I do not want the packet to leave the system if it should not.

EDIT 2 P.S. There is a great way of doing this on Linux. I can achieve everything I mentioned here on Linux with libnetfilter_queue. I will not bother posting solution here because there are many many many tutorials on how to do it on Linux.

In conclusion, I am still looking for answer on how to do this on BSD. As far as I can understand, I need to write a wrapper/library based on pf (because there is no such thing on the net - otherwise I should have found it already), that does the same thing as libnetfilter with it's libnetfilter_queue library. Or I could somehow dig into libnetfilter and port it to FreeBSD, but since it is based on iptables, only thing I can get from digging into libnetfilter library is logic and algorithms not the actual code itself, which by itself could prove to be of no use to me.

Comment: PCAP is just a nice interface for BPF which has a horrible syntax involving assembly macros(although I got through it somehow). you can only sniff packets with PCAP.

Comment: PCAP is packet capture library, written by tcpdump fellows it is not meant for packet manipulation, you are probably confusing the PCAP filters with the actual filtering of traffic. PCAP filters are used for filter what traffic to capture not the actual packets. [here is the link](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

Comment: ouch nvm, sorry for the confusion-previous comments deleted not to confuse further readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD 9.1 has an userspace framework for packet access called netmap. It was recently introduced and has an amazing performance scale. It does very simple but powerful thing - just mmaps the NIC buffers to userspace portion of memory and detaches the packet processing from host stack, this was exactly what I needed the rest is on me.

If anyone needs any goods reference for this, please refer to [man netmap (4)](http://www.manualpages.de/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-8.3-RELEASE/man4/netmap.4.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OpenDPI](https://github.com/thomasbhatia/OpenDPI) or [nDPI](http://www.ntop.org/products/ndpi/).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but those are both libpcap based traffic sniffers. I have Found the answer to my questions and will update the post to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Divert Sockets" in BSD implementation as well. Unlike Netmap, it is not zero-copy (IMHO) however it can work with ipfw in order to implement the necessary filters in order to filter packages you want to process.